# Need to store strings, numbers and multidimensional numpy arrays together on disk

Tags: python, numpy, save

My app needs to save the fields of an object to disk so they can be easily loaded again later. Currently I'm just pickling the entire object and compressing the file with gzip, but the files are still huge (I assume because of the arrays) and take longer than I'd like to save. Is there some way to store the arrays better? Or a different approach entirely?

cPickle doesn't seem to improve the speed. And I've looked into HDF5 h5py for storing the arrays, but I'd like to keep everything together. This is my first time working on a problem like this, so if there is a nice combination of solutions I'd appreciate it.

Comment: How huge is huge, how slow is slow? Also, are you first storing, then compressing, or are you doing compression on the fly?

Comment: Are the numpy arrays dense or sparse? Did you try using the alternative pickle protocol? I would suggest using protocol 2 for efficiency. Also, numpy can save binary files directly with `numpy.save` (or `savez` for multiple arrays and `savez_compressed` for compressed multiple arrays - you can put strings in a numpy array no problems).